# How can I make parameter in method valid?

Tags: php, function, symfony, methods, parameters

In a method in my entity I am using a parameter "addlinkedDocuments".

```
class Documents {
  /**
  * Many Documents link to many Documents.
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Documents", fetch="EAGER")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="documents_documents",
  *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="link_origin", referencedColumnName="id")},
  *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="link_destination", referencedColumnName="id")}
  *      )
  * @Groups("documents")
  */
  private $linkedDocuments;


  public function __construct() {
    $this->linkedDocuments = new ArrayCollection();
  }



  /**
  * @return Collection|linkedDocuments[]
  */
  public function getlinkedDocuments(): Collection
  {
    return $this->linkedDocuments;
  }

  public function addlinkedDocuments(linkedDocuments $linkedDocuments): self
  {
    if (!$this->linkedDocuments->contains($linkedDocuments)) {
      $this->linkedDocuments[] = $linkedDocuments;
    }

    return $this;
  }

  public function removelinkedDocuments(linkedDocuments $linkedDocuments): self
  {
    if ($this->linkedDocuments->contains($linkedDocuments)) {
      $this->linkedDocuments->removeElement($linkedDocuments);
    }

    return $this;
  }
```

But I get the error message:

> The type hint of parameter "linkedDocuments" in method
>   "addlinkedDocuments" in class "App\Entity\Documents" is invalid.

Comment: Is `linkedDocuments` a type ?

Comment: @frz3993 it is an ArrayCollection. I added some more information to my question

Comment: if it is an ArrayCollection, surely the typehint would need to be an ArrayCollection.

Comment: I mean the linkDocuments in the method definition `(linkedDocuments $linkedDocuments)`. You can typehint with native type, class or interface. Example `function something(string $filename)` - I am hinting that the method must take a string as `$filename`

Comment: I don't recommend this, but removing the hinting will probably work. Like this `public function removelinkedDocuments($linkedDocuments)`

Comment: Ok, the first recommendation you made I do not understand properly. Can you say it again? `public function addlinkedDocuments(linkedDocuments $linkedDocuments)` is what I wrote. But isn't this what you recommended? `function something(string $filename)`

Comment: removing the hinting worked.. But should I do this, when you do not recommend it?

Comment: Your naming is inconsistent and confusing.  addLinkedDocuments implies that you are adding 1 or more documents i.e. an array.  But $this->linkedDocuments[] = $linkedDocuments; implies that $linkedDocuments is only one document.  So do you add one document at a time or multiple documents?

Comment: That was an example. I use type hinting to make sure the method will get what it expect to get or exception/error is thrown. If the method expect to receive a string as argument(like the example) and I pass an array `$obj->something([1, 2, 3])`, php will throw error/exception. Should you do it or not depends on your use case.  I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: you have to type hint on classes, not on your class variables - so either use ArrayCollection as typehint or the Collection Interface itself.

Comment: @Cerad I am adding one document at a time

Comment: @Rufinus but the name of my ArrayCollection is `linkedDocuments` right? So I use this name, or you mean something else

Comment: the name and the type of the array are two different things! you initialice it as arraycollection in the constructor. so the type hint is either 
ArrayCollection or the Collection Interface.

Comment: @monkeylove Okay. The Bananaapple answer below covers most of the changes you need to make.  However it would be easier to maintain if you correctly indicated the pluralization.  So change Documents to Document.  Change addlinkedDocuments(Documents $linkedDocuments) to addlinkedDocument(Document $linkedDocument) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you got a self referential many to many relationship on `Documents`.

Any given Document can therefore be related to many other Documents.

`linkedDocuments` is merely the name of the variable that holds the collection of `Documents`.

My point is that the linked documents are not of type `linkedDocuments` but `Documents`, so your type-hint should be changed accordingly:

```
/**
 * @return Collection|Document[]
 */
 public function getlinkedDocuments(): Collection
 {
     return $this->linkedDocuments;
 }

 public function addlinkedDocument(Document $linkedDocument): self
 {
     if (!$this->linkedDocuments->contains($linkedDocument)) {
         $this->linkedDocuments[] = $linkedDocument;
     } 

     return $this;
 }

 public function removelinkedDocument(Document $linkedDocument): self
 {
     if ($this->linkedDocuments->contains($linkedDocument)) {
         $this->linkedDocuments->removeElement($linkedDocument);
     }

     return $this;
 }
```

**EDIT:** As per Cerad's suggestion I have gone and renamed the methods to better reflect plurality. So your class should be called `Document` so that any one given document can be linked to many documents.

Comment: Might consider adjusting the naming per my last comment on the question.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good shout @Cerad - I've updated my answer accordingly.